# Koudoku runs fine locally but crashes on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently installed the [Koudoku gem](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku) and it works great on my computer but when I push to heroku now, the application has an error and the logs look like this below.  Does anyone know why I am getting an error about the application_helper? I don't have that specific file in my project normally but I believe the Koudoku engine adds it in during runtime. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I don't have an answer but I suspect that this could be due to how engines are initialized. I have set the following line in my config/application.rb file:
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
I think this might prevent the initializer from loading unless I add something to my lib/engine.rb per this blog post:
http://octothought.com/precompiling-assets-for-a-rails-engine-on-heroku/

Can anyone help me understand how I can adapt the code they add to their engine.rb to my situation? They say: "The magic incantation for that is to pass a special :group => :assets or :group => :all option to your engine’s initializer, and make sure you configure your precompiled in that initializer." but then in the actual code they talk about rocket engines which confuses me.

```
initializer "RocketEngine asset precompile", :group => :all do |app|
  app.config.assets.precompile += %w(
    rocket.css 
    rocket.js
  )
end
```

This is my actual error on heroku:

```
 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 54469 -e production`
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/koudoku-9e73e64e5520/app/controllers/koudoku/application_controller.rb:4:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:308:in `depend_on'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
 app[web.1]: Exiting
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:349:in `require_or_load'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers': Missing helper file helpers/application_helper.rb (AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError)
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding application_helper.rb to app/helpers:

```
module ApplicationHelper
end
```

And also importing the ApplicationHelper in the controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```